# What does it mean to say that a pair of points are antipodal in a topological sphere?

Tags: algebraic-topology

A pair of points are antipodal if they are diametrically opposite to each other. This definition makes perfect sense when one thinks of the unit 2-sphere centered at the origin and embedded in $R^3$; that is, the set of all points for which $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

However, what does it mean to say that a pair of points are antipodal in a topological sphere? If this question doesn't make sense, I fail to recognize when two points are antipodal when considering, say, an ellipsoid. For example, how does one make sense of the [Borsuk–Ulam theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) for the ellipsoid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of "antipodal" depends on a choice of homeomorphism between an ellipsoid (or any other subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic to a sphere) and the usual unit sphere. The Borsuk-Ulam theorem is true regardless of this choice.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking along these lines as I was writing the question, but it's nice to see this verified.